# Extract sub-page links by Looping Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Extract sub-page links by Looping Python

I need to extract only the links of the "Next" at the bottom of all the "A category " stock pages using a dynamic loop.
I am new to python, but coded the same in VB and running in fine.
This code must be infested with syntax errors , do bear with it.

Help will be appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

sub_link=[]
sub_link_edit=[]

 def convert(url):
  if not url.startswith('http://'):
    return 'http:' + url
  return url

next_link = 'https://money.rediff.com/companies/groups/A'

while next_link:
 page = requests.get(next_link)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,,'html.parser')

 pagination_container_company = soup.find_all("table", class_="pagination- 
 container-company")[0].text

sub_link = re.search('href="(.*)">Next', 
pagination_container_company).group(1)
sub_link_edit.append(convert(sub_link))
next_link=convert(sub_link)

data_df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame(
 {
    'Link': sub_link_edit
 })
data_df = pd.concat([data_df, df], sort=False)

print(df.shape)
tot_sub=len(sub_link_edit)
print(tot_sub)

data_df.to_csv('results_1.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I decided to edit my answer. since you want to do it automatically this code will get all the "Next" URLs one after the other until there are none left then it will save them to a CSV file called `urls.csv`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

csv_file = "page number,url\n"
url = "https://money.rediff.com/companies/groups/A"
urls = [url]

while True:
    data = requests.get(url).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find_all(class_="pagination-container-company")[0]
    row = table.find_all("a", text="Next")

    if row:
        url = "https:" + row[0]["href"]
        urls.append(url)
    else:
        break


for index, url in enumerate(urls):
    csv_file += f"{index},{url}\n"

with open("urls.csv", "w") as o:
    o.write(csv_file)
```

===============================

[old answer] do you really need all this code just to extract the next page link?. the link for each page is of the form `https://money.rediff.com/companies/groups/A/<number>` where `<number>` the number of the page

Comment: Thanks it worked. I am just beginning to  build python code, I get to know different styles of coding when I take a  circuitous journey.

Answer (score 0):

@MaxSmith060 is probably right, but I wanted to offer a technical explanation as well.

I didn't take too much of a detailed look at your code but at a high level, this is what I would do if I wanted to iteratively get the link for the "next" page.

First, inspect element on the link:

[image]

Then, filter down to something unique - `class=pagination-container-company` looks promising.

```py
next_link = "..."

while next_link:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(next_link)

    pagination_container_company = soup.find_all("table", class_="pagination-container-company")[0].text

    next_link = re.search('href="(.*)">Next', pagination_container_company).group(1)
```

Some simple grouping regex to extract the link and then you have the link.

Comment: I have edited my code based on your inputs , but yet not successful.

Comment: Please guide me.

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: okay, so either `find_all` found more than one table or the regex didn't work for some reason - check out regexr.com and you should be able to play around with the soup output to make sure it's working